# UI dashboard that triggers a map reduce job on Hadoop and sends email when complete

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to build a UI tool where users can submit their expression and based on that expression an MR job gets triggered in the backend on the Hadoop cluster. When the MR job is complete, an email needs to go out with the result summary in the email body.

I have never executed MR jobs in such manner before and am quite confused as to how I can achieve this. Is there any framework that can help me ? or any ideas as to how to go about implementing it on my own ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a component called Oozie in hadoop which is a workflow system. This will schedule or automate the MapReduce jobs. Your application needs to coordinate with the Hadoop API and I think the better way to start is to explore Oozie API and do a feasibility study on your project. Its good idea and it is doable. There are a lot of applications built on top of Hadoop. Good luck!

http://oozie.apache.org/

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/WebServicesAPI.html

Comment: Thanks. This definitely seems useful.  We don't have oozie setup on the cluster so I am going to have to convince somebody to get it done.